# How to also download duplicate images?

Tags: wget

I have a list of 900 URLs. Each page contains one image. Some images are duplicates (with same URL). I want to download 900 images, *including* duplicates.

I was able to download all pages and the embedded images (and ignored all other file types) with wget. But it seems to me that wget "ignores" an image when it was already downloaded before. So I had 900 pages, but only around 850 images.

(How) can I tell wget to download duplicates, too? It could append `_1`, `_2`, … at the file name.

---

My wget command:

`wget --input-file=urls.txt --output-file=log.txt --wait 1 --random-wait --page-requisites --exclude-domains code.jquery.com --span-hosts --reject thumbnail*.png -P downloadfolder`

Comment: Have you tried downloading images with `-o` flag?

Comment: This should be the default behavior, if you run `wget` with no other option. What command are you running exactly?

Comment: @Gilles: I added the wget command I used to my question. This is default behavior? Wouldn't that mean that you'd get the very same CSS file (with `-p`) for each page you download?

Comment: @Karlson: `-o` (same as `--output-file`) activates the log, right? I used this parameter. How could it help me? I tried to make sense out of the log file, but couldn't spot any information about duplicate images.

Comment: @unor Sorry I meant `-O`.  Which allows you to save with a different name.

Comment: @Karlson When you utilize -O then you need to know the name of the file you are downloading and make a variant of of it in some way, shape or form, or give it a totally random name. I haven't been able to find a way to accomplish this using any command line switches of wget, to create versions of a file such as file;1 ... file;6 (anmyone remember Open VMS days ? :-))

Comment: @silencedhaven I do remember *cringe* but you already know what you are downloading all you need to do is to choose a different name for a local target.  Unless of course you are simply doing a recursive directory load in which case how do you have duplicates?

Comment: @Karlson Yes I see your point but what I mean is, you need an outside construct (other than wget command switches) to make up a destination filename, that some how resembles to the original filename.

Comment: @silencedhaven It doesn't have to but I see your point.

Comment: @Karlson: I tried `-O foo`, but it seems to save *everything* in the same file then. It gives a warning about it: it's the case when you use `-O` in combination with `-r` or `-p` (where the latter is the case for me).

Comment: @unor If you don't change the file name you're saving as it will obviously save everything under the same name.

Answer (score 1):

wget doesn't ignore the duplicates, it is most probably overwriting them.
wget has a lot of options and I am not aware of all of them but I don't believe there is such an option to selectively add a suffix to discriminate duplicate filenames. You need to build this functionality yourself.

such as

```
#  mkdir /myarchivedir
#  
#  mkdir /tmp/mytempdir
#  cd /tmp/mytempdir
#  
#  i=1
#  while [ $i -le 900 ] 
#  do
#  wget http://mysite.com/somefile
#  file=$(ls)
#  mv $file /myarchivedir/${i}.${file}
#  (( i=$i+1 ))
#  done
```

as you can see, even if the $file variable is the same as another one before, since the i is changing value every time, when you move the file to /myarchivedir, it will not overwrite your duplicate named image.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? I'm not that savvy with scripts. I guess this can be used as bash script? Karlson added `#` in front of every line, but I'd need to remove those because this is the comment symbol?

Comment: @unor This is not a script.  These are commands and `#` is the command prompt.

Comment: `#` generally indicates running as root. Is it really necessary to run this script as root? Otherwise, I'd replace these with `$`, which generally indicate running as a non-root user.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is `--page-requisites`. I suspect it will recognize the duplicates and avoids downloading them again. This is usually what you want. You get around it by calling wget once for each URL and have it download to a different folder each time, like so:

```
#!/bin/bash
let i=0
while IFS=$'\n' read url; do 
  let i++; 
  wget -nv -P $i --page-requisites "$url"; 
done < urls.txt
```

However, you only need the single image contained in each of the files. This should do the trick:

```
wget -i urls.txt -q -O - | ...extract image URLs... | wget -nv -i -
```

Extracting the URLs from the HTML can be as easy as looking for some verbatim URLs, e.g.

```
grep -Eo 'http://host/abc/[^"]+.jpg'
```

Or you need a little more effort. If your 900 URLs point to similar HTML it should not be a problem. In any case this will number the files on name collision.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it's not saving duplicates for you is because you are using the `--page-requisites` (`-p`) option. Try adding the `--no-directories` (`-nd`) option to your command.

From the manpage (strong emphasis added by me):

> When running Wget **without** -N, -nc, -r, or **-p**, downloading the same file in the same directory will result in the original copy of file being preserved and the second copy being named file.1.  If that file is downloaded yet again, the third copy will be named file.2, and so on.  (**This is also the behavior with -nd, even if -r or -p are in effect.**)